# How do I enable Wayland on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, wayland

When selecting my account on the login screen I do see the gear icon in the bottom right-hand corner. My options are "Ubuntu" and "Plasma." I can't find "Ubuntu with Wayland" anywhere.

```
$ grep Wayland /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
#WaylandEnable=false
```

I've also tried deleting my `.config`, `.local`, and `.cache` directories but the option still doesn't show up.

After installing LightDM, I see the option. Although when I select it and try to log in, it just flickers and shows the login page again.

I have a suspicion that this might be because I have the closed-source nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: whats the output of `ls /usr/share/wayland-sessions`

Comment: ubuntu-wayland.desktop

Comment: Ok.. I too faced this problem before.. But could not find the solution..

Comment: you can try a workaround just to confirm.. workaround is to install lightdm package and configure it for login greeter.. check.. then remove the package..

Comment: Thanks! When I install lightdm I see the option. Although when I select it and try to log in, it just flickers and shows the login page again. I have a suspicion that this might be because I have the closed-source nvidia drivers install but at this point it seems like a separate question.

Comment: yes.. your catch on nvidia drivers is the issue. so gdm detected that there is a problem with graphics and thus it is not showing the option.. so configure gdm3 for the greeter and remove the lightdm package. Then search for "graphics related to wayland" Questions..